# Parse markdown reference with markdown-it

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, markdown

I'm using [`markdown-it`](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) to parse a markdown file. The source I have is this:

```
![Build Status][1]

[1]: https://travis-ci.org/paulmillr/es6-shim.svg
```

I've been using [MarkdownIt.parse](https://markdown-it.github.io/markdown-it/#MarkdownIt.parse) to get parsed data, however now it's failing me.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'references' of undefined
    at Array.reference (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/markdown-it/lib/rules_block/reference.js:182:23)
    at ParserBlock.tokenize (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/markdown-it/lib/parser_block.js:79:20)
    at ParserBlock.parse (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/markdown-it/lib/parser_block.js:118:8)
    at Array.block (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/markdown-it/lib/rules_core/block.js:14:20)
    at Core.process (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/markdown-it/lib/parser_core.js:51:13)
    at MarkdownIt.parse (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/markdown-it/lib/index.js:493:13)
    at promiseRipple.processNodes (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/test-markdown-it.js:317:23)
    at /Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/promise-ripple.js:13:28
    at tryCatcher (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at ReductionPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/reduce.js:109:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:582:26)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:693:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/thomas/Desktop/es6-shim/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:371:17)
```

There's a live demo [here](https://markdown-it.github.io/) of markdown it. I dropped my source in and it works perfectly. On that page there's a `debug` tab and the exact output I expected is there.

How can I resolve this bug and get the expected output using [`markdown-it`](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it)?

Is there another method I can call that can give me the correct output?

It seems that [MarkdownIt.parse](https://markdown-it.github.io/markdown-it/#MarkdownIt.parse) takes an `env` and it's [directly tied to the line thats throwing the error](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it/blob/master/lib/rules_block/reference.js#L182).

I'm using version 4.4.0 (unpublished on NPM, master tag on github).

Here's some source code:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var markdown = fs.readFileSync('./readme.md', 'utf8')
var MarkdownIt = require('markdown-it')
var md = new MarkdownIt()
var parsedMd = md.parse(markdown)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this solved it:

```
var parsedMd = md.parse(markdown, {})
```